# Does path require to be normalize before getting relative Path?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out a test case which can fail if I remove the normalize function.
for following code

```
    public static String relativizeAndNormalizePath(final String baseDirectory, final String path) {
        final String resultPath;
        if (baseDirectory == null) {
            resultPath = path;
        }
        else {
            final Path pathAbsolute = Paths.get(path).normalize();
            final Path pathBase = Paths.get(baseDirectory).normalize();
            resultPath = pathBase.relativize(pathAbsolute).toString();
        }
        return resultPath;
    }
```

does it affect any functionality if `normalize()` is removed from pathAbsolute and pathBase.

I have tried some ways but it doesn't make any affect in `resultPath` if I remove normalize.
I am expecting a test case so that if I remove the normalize function from `pathAbsolute` and `pathBase` my test case would fail.

Comment: The result may look different in some cases, but will always have the same meaning and will point to the same location, whether or not you call `normalize()`.